# Unable to create an array from a table

Tags: matlab, csv, import, subset, matlab-table

I'm trying to load an external CSV file using MATLAB.

I managed to download it using `webread`, but I only need a subset of the columns.

I tried

```
Tb = webread('https://datahub.io/machine-learning/iris/r/iris.csv');     
X = [sepallength sepalwidth petallength petalwidth];
```

But I cannot form `X` this way because the names are not recognized. How can I create `X` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
Tb = webread('https://datahub.io/machine-learning/iris/r/iris.csv');
```

Produces a `table` object with **column names** you later try to access *as if they were workspace variables* - which they aren't. Instead, you should modify your code to use:

```
X = [Tb.sepallength Tb.sepalwidth Tb.petallength Tb.petalwidth];
```